# Change the background color of a pop-up dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, background-color

I wrote android code that shows a pop-up dialog but I want to change the background color from black to white , and then the color of the writing.

This is the dialog's code:

```
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

    if (!welcomeScreenShown) {


        String whatsNewText = getResources().getString(R.string.Text);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(whatsNewText).setPositiveButton(
                R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
    }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you just want a light theme and aren't particular about the specific color, then you can pass a theme id to the AlertDialog.Builder constructor.

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)...
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT)...
```

Comment: it says deprecated now? Any suggestions to do so now?

Comment: @Dinesh If you are using Android Studio, it will directly tell you the replacement: *Deprecated Use android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert*

Answer (score 129):

To expand on @DaneWhite's answer, you don't have to rely on the built-in themes. You can easily supply your own style:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/myColor</item>
</style>
```

and then apply it in the Builder constructor:

Java:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme)
        ...
        .create();
```

Kotlin:

```
var alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
        ...
        .create()
```

This should work whether you are using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` or `android.app.AlertDialog`

This also works better than @DummyData's answer because you don't resize the dialog. If you set window's background drawable you overwrite some existing dimensional information and get a dialog that is not standard width.

If you set background on theme and the set the theme on dialog you'll end up with a dialog that is colored how you want but still the correct width.

Comment: How can I change text and buttons colors?

Comment: You should use the `android:windowBackground` theme attribute instead. `android:background` will change the background color of every `View`.

Comment: Actually, both `background` and `windowBackground` remove rounded corners from the dialog window. If you want to set a color, you should use `colorBackground` attribute instead.

Comment: This solution additionally change text color to more darker in the dialog

Comment: if using MaterialComponents, I found the only thing that worked without removing rounded corners was to set`android:backgroundTint`

Answer (score 53):

**Credit goes to [Sushil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346970/3171162)**

Create your AlertDialog as usual:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
Dialog dialog = dialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

**After** calling show() on your dialog, set the background color like this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.background_dark);
```

Comment: Be careful. While this will set the background color, you will replace the previous background drawable, which contained width dimension. Your resulting dialog may be different size than if you didn't update background drawable.

Comment: I wish we could do it via theme resource using some style attr. I think there must be this possibility to set not color, but any other drawable background resource.

Answer (score 32):

To change the background color of **all** dialogs and pop-ups in your app, use `colorBackgroundFloating` attribute.

```
<style name="MyApplicationTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
...
<item name="colorBackgroundFloating">
    @color/background</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating" tools:targetApi="23">
    @color/background</item>
...
</style>
```

Documentation:

[colorBackgroundFloating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#colorBackgroundFloating)

Answer (score 26):

With the **Material Components Library** you can just use the default [**`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md):

```
    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(AlertDialogActivity.this,
        R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog_Background)
        .setTitle("Dialog")
        .setMessage("Message...  ....")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
        .show();
```

where the theme overlay `ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog_Background` is:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog_Background" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <!-- Background Color-->
    <item name="android:background">@color/.....</item>
    <!-- Text Color for title and message -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/......</item>
    <!-- Style for positive button -->
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <!-- Style for negative button -->
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <!-- text color for the button -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/.....</item>
    <!-- Background tint for the button -->
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking at the https://material.io/components/dialogs/android#full-screen-dialog where the container color element has no attribute. I was trying to edit the colorSurface property but was getting nothing. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 16):

For any dialog called `myDialog`, after calling `myDialog.show();` you can call:

```
myDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, CUSTOM_COLOR));
```

where `CUSTOM_COLOR` is in 8-digit hex format, ex. `0xFF303030`. Here, `FF` is the alpha value and the rest is the color value in hex.

Comment: +1, much better solution than using `setBackgroundDrawableResource` as you don't have to worry about the size or shape components. You can also use `... .setColorFilter(int color, Mode mode)`, where `color` would be the color code int you can get from the likes of `getColor(int resId)`, and for `mode` you can use `Mode.SRC` to override the previous color entirely.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom alertDialog and use a xml layout. in the layout, you can set the background color and textcolor.

Something like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ActivityName.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
dialog.setContentView(view);
```

Comment: But can I just add a line of code to change the color without do all this stuff?

Comment: May be you can try this : getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);

Comment: I hope you are writing it in correct place and getting your alertDialog window only..

Comment: if you add YOUR_DIALOG.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);    it will work for you...

Answer (score 3):

I order to change the dialog buttons and background colors, you will need to extend the Dialog theme, eg.:

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonsStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonsStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light.blue</item>
</style>
```

After that, you need to pass this custom style to the dialog builder, eg. like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.MyDialogStyle)
```

If you want to change the color of the text inside the dialog, you can pass a custom view to this Builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View)
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder.setView(@LayoutResource int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shape XML in drawable

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Add this line after creating an alert dialog

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ATextActivity.this,R.drawable.color_drawable));
```

If you do not want to create XML
you can try this below code

Create a drawable of color

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
```

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(contex.getDrawable(R.drawable.container_dialog));
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

Use `setInverseBackgroundForced(true)` on the alert dialog builder to invert the background.