# Remove Black background from Alert Dialog Box - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am working on an Android Application , Here I have created a custom dialog box , The dialog box was appearing on complete height of the device , but I wanted to leave margins from top and bottom , so I set margin using below code

```
  WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = Utility.convertDPtoPixel(400, screen);

    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Above code worked perfectly, but the dialog appears with black surroundings.

Here is the screen shot:

[image: Screen shot with black surroundings]

Now I want to remove these black surroundings from the dialog box.

Here is the code of dialog box:

```
public void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    final AlertDialog alertDialog;
    //final Dialog alertDialog;
    Context mContext;
    mContext = screen;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LoginActivity.screen.getSystemService(LoginActivity.screen.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countrylist, null);
    LinearLayout rellayout = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.rellayout);

    RelativeLayout closeAcessCodeDialog = (RelativeLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.closeAcessCodeDialog) ;

    ListView listview = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter1(LoginActivity.screen, countryList));

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.screen);
    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = Utility.convertDPtoPixel(400, screen);

    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                                long id) {
            countryName = idCountry.get(pos);
            System.out.println("Country code is: " + countryName);
            alertDialog.cancel();
            text.setText(countryList.get(pos));
        }
    });

    closeAcessCodeDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

**countrylist.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffe264"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rellayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/listview"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Select your Country"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/closeAcessCodeDialog"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeDialog"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/close_country_dialog" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="#e5e5e5"
            android:background="@drawable/list_bacground"
            android:dividerHeight="1px" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I visited many similar links over stackoverflow , but no one was helpfull .

Comment: Change your activity theme with Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar in androidmanifest and its done.

Comment: If theme doesn't work then change setBackgroundDrawableResource to 
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
hope this helps you.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I tried with theme , It's not working .

Comment: Try the second answer

Comment: @AndyDeveloper The second option I am using already in the code .

Comment: I tried with both the one you suggested and the second one I am using .

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18348490/7413139) i think it help u

Comment: @vaibhav the link you suggested ,It worked partially . It has reduced black area .

Comment: Use **Dialog fragment** instead of alert dialog. you have more control over that then alert dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Hope this will help you a lot

I think its default theme color which is Black so you have to check the import of your `AlertDialog` it should be `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;` and one more thing you should use custom color for Background like below

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: By changing package and putting alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable() just after show() method worked , great Man !

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.show();
```