# Is there any way to remove the background of an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, colors, background, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to change the background color of an Android AlertDialog.

Every post I've seen is about changing the color of the AlertDialog, but not the background behind.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can reduce the dim Amount

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.5f);
```

To get a background color you need to make a custom Alert Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:background">@color/myColor</item>
```

and then apply it in the Builder constructor:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme)
    ...
    .create();
```

for more info see [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346920/change-the-background-color-of-a-pop-up-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do what you asked for but its not that much of a good solution

First, set custom dialog theme like this.

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**CustomDialog.java**

Apply the theme and construct your custom_dialog view as follows.

```
 public HTCustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
}
```

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_solid_80">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_popup"
        android:padding="16dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now that CustomDialog view is a full-screen view, set background of your root layout to whatever color you'd like.

[image]

I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227126/how-can-i-change-default-black-dim-background-color-not-the-amount-of-dim-of) take a look .